# I couldn't get *ngIf to work...turns out it was a typo in my code

Tags: javascript, html, web, angular9

I'm new to Angular 9. I'm trying to do something simple but it doesn't work. I'm trying to display my name based on a Boolean but when I add *ngIf to the div nothing appears.

```html
<div *ngIf="booTest">
  <h1>Cory</h1>
</div>
```

Here's the component

```html
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  boolTest = true;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: `public boolTest = true;`

Comment: it was a typo. I wrote *ngIf="booTest"....it shouldve been BoolTest

Comment: In that case, I think that you should delete this question, as it probably won't help many in the future.

Comment: I agree. I'm also new to stacked overflow. How do I delete a comment?

Comment: No stress, SO sees posts like this all the time, happens to everyone. When you hover a comment, there should be a delete button appear that you can click. Note that if you delete your question, then all answers and comments under it will also be deleted :) .

Answer (score 1):

#### Spelling

It is booTest in one place, and boolTest in another.

Comment: I know. Thanks! It was a bonehead typo. I have to be more careful.